# Command-line argument in C

Tags: c

I am very new to C programming. I am stuck in a very trivial problem. I have a C program where I am passing the value of one variable through a text file. Based on this variable I am passing one condition, e.g. `if bDrw==true then proceed else not`. Now I want my program to take the condition from from the command line instead of a text file. i.e. when I type "Drw" on the command line, the program should make `bDrw==true.`

How can I do this?
I am giving the rest of arguents through :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
bool    bArgs = false;
bool    bConf = false;
bool    bUgMgr = false;
bool    bFile = false;
bool    bErp  = false;

char    acAttrFile[(MAX_FSPEC_SIZE*2) + 1 ]="";
char    acPartFile[(MAX_FSPEC_SIZE*2) + 1 ]="";
char    acConfFile[(MAX_FSPEC_SIZE*2) + 1 ]="";
char    acSingleItem[UF_UGMGR_PARTNO_SIZE + 1]="";
char    acItemRevSeed[UF_UGMGR_PARTNO_SIZE + UF_UGMGR_PARTREV_SIZE + 1]="";
char    acUser[MAX_FSPEC_SIZE + 1]="";
char    acPass[MAX_FSPEC_SIZE + 1]="";
char    acLogDir[(MAX_FSPEC_SIZE*2) + 1]="";
char    acNatDir[(MAX_FSPEC_SIZE*2) + 1]="";
char    msg[MAX_LINE_SIZE + 1]="";

bArgs = getArgs(argc,argv,acAttrFile,acPartFile,acConfFile,acSingleItem,acItemRevSeed,acUser,acPass,acLogDir,acNatDir,&bUgMgr,&bErp);
```

Comment: Have you tried pulling it from `argv` yet?

Comment: What does your current code look like?  What does your `main` function look like?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming c99:

```
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, void **argv)
{
    bool bDrw = false;
    if (argc > 1  && strcmp(argv[1], "bDrw") == 0)
        bDrw = true;
    /* take it from here.... */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also be including `stdbool.h`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming you run the program by typing its name followed by `Drw`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
...
  if(argc > 1 && strncmp("Drw",argv[1],4) == 0)
  {
     ...  // bDrw is true
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial:

- http://wwwx.cs.unc.edu/~sparkst/howto/cpp_main.php

Comment: Actually I am pasing all the arguements through here :
getArgs(argc,argv,acAttrFile,acPartFile,acConfFile,acSingleItem,acItemRevSeed,acUser,acPass,acLogDir,acNatDir,&bUgMgr,&bErp);

Comment: OK, then you just need to do what others suggested, depending on how you want to do it - either put the code in main and pass a new `bDrw` variable as you are passing e.g. `acAttrFile` or do the `if(bDrw)` check right there and determine whether to continue or not.

Answer (score 0):

For complex argument parsing, you should consider the [**`getopt`**](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) library.

However, in this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    unsigned short int bDrw = 0;

    if ( argc == 2 && strcmp( argv[1], "Drw" ) == 0 ) {
        bDrw = 1;
    }

    printf( "bDrw = %d\n", bDrw );

    return 0;
}
```